# Why is the variable returned from a closure always one step behind

Tags: ios, swift, closures

In the following code the closure accesses a REST API to call a function on an embedded uC, then read a value from the uC.  The problem is that the value returned to the variable "result" below, is always one step behind.  Meaning, when I turn on the LED and ask for the value of light from the light sensor, I should get the value expected when the light is on.  But I don't.  I get the value for the light off.  If I then turn off the LED, I get the value for the light on.  I have the device in front of me so I can visually confirm the state.

My question is, what is it about closure behavior that is causing the value of result to be one step behind, and, is there any way to get the current value, instead of the previous value?

```
@IBAction func lightOn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let funcArgs = [1]
    myPhoton!.callFunction("lightLed0", withArguments: funcArgs) { (resultCode : NSNumber!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.lightStateLabel.text = "LED is on"
        }
    }
    myPhoton!.getVariable("Light", completion: { (result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if let e = error {
            self.getLightLabel.text = "Failed reading light"
        }
        else {
            if let res = result as? Float {
                self.getLightLabel.text = "Light level is \(res) lumens"
            }
        }
    })



}


@IBAction func lightOff(sender: AnyObject) {
    let funcArgs = [0]
    myPhoton!.callFunction("lightLed0", withArguments: funcArgs) { (resultCode : NSNumber!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.lightStateLabel.text = "LED is off"
        }
    }
    myPhoton!.getVariable("Light", completion: { (result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if let e = error {
            self.getLightLabel.text = "Failed reading light"
        }
        else {
            if let res = result as? Float {
                self.getLightLabel.text = "Light level is \(res) lumens"
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Asynchronous code doesn't run synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess.

`callFunction` uses a REST API. So it is asynchronous.

`getVariable` either uses a REST API and is also asynchronous or else uses a local record of state as returned by the last REST call.

At best you've created a race condition in which `callFunction` may not complete before `getVariable`. At worst it's basically guaranteed not to assuming reasonable concurrency controls.

Solution: don't call `getVariable` until `callFunction` has completed.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me how to know that callFunction has completed, and how to hold of the getVariable until then?

Answer (score 1):

The web request you are making is occurring asynchronously. As a result, it is possible that the value you are retrieving has not yet been updated. Try nesting your call to `getVariable` in the completion handler of `callFunction`. Something like this could work:

```
@IBAction func lightOn(sender: AnyObject) {
    let funcArgs = [1]

    myPhoton!.callFunction("lightLed0", withArguments: funcArgs) { (resultCode : NSNumber!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.lightStateLabel.text = "LED is on"
        }

        self.myPhoton!.getVariable("Light", completion: { (result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if let e = error {
                self.getLightLabel.text = "Failed reading light"
            }
            else {
                if let res = result as? Float {
                    self.getLightLabel.text = "Light level is \(res) lumens"
                }
            }
        })
    }
}


@IBAction func lightOff(sender: AnyObject) {
    let funcArgs = [0]
    myPhoton!.callFunction("lightLed0", withArguments: funcArgs) { (resultCode : NSNumber!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.lightStateLabel.text = "LED is off"
        }

        self.myPhoton!.getVariable("Light", completion: { (result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if let e = error {
                self.getLightLabel.text = "Failed reading light"
            }
            else {
                if let res = result as? Float {
                    self.getLightLabel.text = "Light level is \(res) lumens"
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

As your code is currently, the moment the call to `callFunction` is made, the code would skip the closure (since it's asynchronous) and continue on its path to call `getVariable`. By the time the `callFunction` request is complete, `getVariable` would have already retrieved the outdated information.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It did not work though.  The behavior is exactly the same. Also, you have to add self. before the myPhoton! when you bring the closure into the function (the compiler demanded it).

Comment: I fixed the code now, thank you. Did you write the server backend? If so, try double-checking that it is updating the appropriate values correctly. Also, as a general note, you may want to cast your result to an `Integer` instead of a `Float` since the return value seems to be either 0 or 1.

Comment: The backend is hosted by www.particle.io as part of their REST API service for IoT micro's with internet connections.  Check em out.  Very cool.  I copied parts of the code from an example and yes, I would be fine with integers.  I also tried adding a   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){} inside the getVariable closure, but it did not change that one step behind behavior.

Comment: Make sure you are correctly unwrapping your `myPhoton` variable. If it's not an optional value, you will not need to unwrap it; the `!` can cause some coding issues, as I've experienced in the past.

Comment: myPhoton is declared var myPhoton : SparkDevice?   SparkDevice is part of the mobile SDK from particle.io.    I believe SparkDevice is returned as AnyObject.